# After changing the server to Vercel instead of Heroku. It's can't find data and gives me parse error,

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

This is the error: `VM204:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

This is where I'm getting the error:

```
const useBooks = () => {
const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https:xyz.vercel.app/book')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setBooks(data))
}, [])
return [books, setBooks];
```

}
export default useBooks;

Backend code:

```
 //API for getting all data.
    app.get('/book', async (req, res) => {
        const query = {};
        const cursor = bookCollections.find(query);
        const result = await cursor.toArray();
        res.send(result);
    })
```

Response is 404 not found. and it gives HTML instead of json. How can I fix it? [This is postman response Screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTPt8.png)